# (HTML & CSS) Wont let me change size of a iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have tried all the things I could think of, but it will still not let me change the height/hight no matter how much I try, it will let me change the width though...

HTML (Home Page):

```
<iframe src="sidebar.php" width="20%" hight="800px"></iframe>
```

CSS (Home Page):

```
iframe {
    background-color: #222222;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
}
```

There!

Comment: You should remove the height and width from the iframe and use only the CSS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax error of height , it should be height

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" width="400" height="400">
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/grZkOd

Comment: There was a Syntax error, but that still wont modify the height! {could the reason be because I'm using 'Sublime Text'}

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

**HTML**

```
<iframe src="sidebar.php" ></iframe>
```

**Css**

```
iframe {
    background-color: #222222;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}
```